# Shower water going under the shower curtain

Tags: shower

I have a shower over my bath, but due to the shape of the bath the shower curtain does not cover the entire length of the bath, so sometimes water is getting under the curtain and on to the carpet.

Can anyone suggest anything i can do to stop the water getting onto the floor, I've attached a photo to give you an idea of what it looks like

[image: Corner of bathtub]

Comment: How did this solution work out? Do you have pictures of what you did?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your shower curtain can reach to the wall of the bath surround, a combination of [shower curtain clips](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JK55BU):

[image: shower curtain clips]

and [splash guards](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001A0NBDM) should prevent most of the water from escaping your tub.
[image: bathtub splash guard]

Comment: looks like it should do it, thanks for the info

Comment: Instead of curtain clips, maybe get some aligator clips and clip the curtain right to the splash guard.

Comment: Question, does these clip go on the floor too? the problem is with preventing water from going from under the curtains and spread all over the bathroom

Answer (score 1):

They make [Shower Splash Guards](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&biw=1280&bih=655&tbs=shop:1&q=shower+splash+guard&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m2&aql=&oq=) not sure if it would help in this situation (as it might not look great), but it might be a simple solution to your problem.